# Sum of a series from "0" to "h" is equal to "n", solve for "h": height of a binary tree

Tags: graph-theory

I intend to calculate the height of a binary tree. I think I need to solve the following equation for $h$. Because in a perfect binary tree there is $2^i$ nodes at each $i$th level of the tree:

$\sum_{i=0}^{h}2^{i}=n$

In other words, find $h$ if we have:

$2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^i+...+2^h=n$

---

<s>If we apply $log_2$ to both sides of equation, then we have:</s>

$0+1+2+...+i+...+h=log_{2}n$

Hence we get:

$\frac{h(h+1)}{2}=log_2n$

We can solve this equation for $h$ with algebra.

Based on above calculation, the value of $h$ is not consistent with [properties of binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Properties_of_binary_trees). For example, it is mentioned that:

> In a perfect full binary tree: $n=2^{h+1}-1$

But the above calculations don't imply such a conclusion. I wonder if anybody knows if I'm missing something.

---

I wonder if anybody can give me a hint to solve this equation for $h$:

$2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^i+...+2^h=n$

Comment: Be careful how you apply $\log_2$. The "log a sum" is not the "sum of the logs".

Comment: @mlc Oh, right. I made that mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sum $2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^i+...+2^h=n$ is a [finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  The sum of that series is just what you quote $n=2^{h+1}-1$.  You can try it for a few small values of $h$ and see, then follow the derivation on the Wikipedia page.